# TYPO3: localization condition, sys_language_uid in fluid-template

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

What I would like to achieve is that an image changes depending on what language is selected at that moment.

This is my HTML

```
<f:if condition="{TSFE:sys_language_uid} == 1">
   <f:then>
     <f:link.page pageUid="{settings.rootpid}" class="navbar-brand">
       <img src="fileadmin/branding/brand/images/png/image1.png" alt="Logo {settings.brandname}" />
     </f:link.page>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
      <f:link.page pageUid="{settings.rootpid}" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="fileadmin/branding/brand/images/png/image2.png" alt="Logo {settings.brandname}" />
      </f:link.page>
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

And this is my TS

```
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
   config {
      sys_language_uid = 1
      language = nl
      locale_all = nl_NL.UTF-8
      htmlTag_setParams = lang="nl" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
   }
[global]

[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
   config {
      sys_language_uid = 2
      language = fr
      locale_all = fr_FR.UTF-8
      htmlTag_setParams = lang="fr" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
     }  

[global]
```

I tried a ton of different ways of writing this but can't seem to make it work hopefully somebody can help.

Comment: You are dutch ? als jij meer hulp nodig hebt ... let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using your own distribution, or extend the functionality of some package ...

Try this in your constants.ts (so they are available in the BE constant editor) `myext/Configuration/TypoScript/constants.ts` :

```
myext.configuration {
    logo {
        src {
            # cat=myext/general/05; type=string; label=English Logo
            default = fileadmin/branding/brand/images/png/image0.png
            # cat=myext/general/06; type=string; label=Dutch Logo
            nl = fileadmin/branding/brand/images/png/image1.png
            # cat=myext/general/07; type=string; label=French Logo
            fr = fileadmin/branding/brand/images/png/image2.png
        }
    }
}
```

then this in your setup.ts `myext/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.ts` :

```
page = PAGE
page {
    # Page Main template
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        variables { 

            # Logo
            logoSrc = TEXT
            logoSrc.value = {$myext.configuration.logo.src.default}
        }
    }
}

[globalVar = GP:L=1]
    page.10.variables.logoSrc.value = {$myext.configuration.logo.src.nl}
[end]

[globalVar = GP:L=2]
    page.10.variables.logoSrc.value = {$myext.configuration.logo.src.fr}
[end]
```

now you can simply use `{logoSrc}` in your fluidtemplate

```
 ...
<f:link.page pageUid="{settings.rootpid}" class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="{logoSrc}" alt="Logo {settings.brandname}" />
</f:link.page>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the pre-evaluated boolean to the template. Either from your controller (there you have access to the TSFE) or via TS to the `FLUIDTEMPLATE` object. It's not clear from the question where you are coming from. You should move the condition inline into the `src`, this way you don't duplicate the whole markup, but only switch the value.

Alternatively, you can pre-calculate the `src` value in the controller or TS and just pass it to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can get current languageUid using `viewHelper` something like below.

You **ViewHelper** file.

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\ExtensionKey\ViewHelpers;

class GetLangUidViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {

    /**
    * GetLangUid
    *
    **/
    public function render() {
        return $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid;
    }
}
```

In your fluid template get current laguageUid like below.

```
{namespace L=MyVendor\ExtensionKey\ViewHelpers}

<f:if condition="{L:getLangUid()} == 1">
   <f:then>
     <f:link.page pageUid="{settings.rootpid}" class="navbar-brand">
       <img src="fileadmin/branding/brand/images/png/image1.png" alt="Logo {settings.brandname}" />
     </f:link.page>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
      <f:link.page pageUid="{settings.rootpid}" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="fileadmin/branding/brand/images/png/image2.png" alt="Logo {settings.brandname}" />
      </f:link.page>
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```